# Push item to array in mlab record array

Tags: javascript, mlab

A record in my database:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5b93d84aa9123300043c4f8f"
},
"googleId": "110329027039267241635",
"username": "Carl Junior",
"eoUsers": [
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false
    },
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false
    },
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false
    },
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false,
        earnings: [['1/20', 0.2], ['1/21', 0.1],  // I want to insert item here
    },
     ]]
],
"__v": 0
```

I want to push an item to the database in the list 'earnings', I figured I had to use one of these options: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/insert.html

I can't seem to figure it out though. **How do I push an item to the list I denoted?**

---

SO after inserting the item, the record should look like this:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5b93d84aa9123300043c4f8f"
},
"googleId": "110329027039267241635",
"username": "Carl Junior",
"eoUsers": [
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false
    },
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false
    },
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false
    },
    {
        "username": "1@gmail.com",
        "password": "3",
        "loggedIn": false,
         earnings: [['1/20', 0.2], ['1/21', 0.1],  ['I INSERTED', 0.45]]
    },
],
"__v": 0
```

Comment: do you want to insert earnings into the eoUsers array? (or as its sibling?)

Comment: The difference between the not-updated and updated shows exactly what I want to happen.

Comment: your record is not a valid JSON format, could you please double-check your code?

Comment: @tashakori whops, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

First connect to your database

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
mongoose.connect( SPECIAL_KEY , { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Then find the record in your collection using the userSchema I suppose you already have created.

```
const User = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);  // where 'user' is the name of your collection
```

Find the record, by eg. _id, that contains the variable that you want to update

```
userSchema.findOne({_id: '5b93d84aa9d1a300043c4f8f'})
        .then(OldUserRecord => {
                //Create a new user record, which will be used to overwrite the old
            const newUserRecord_eoUsers = OldUserRecord.eoUsers;
            newUserRecord_eoUsers[3].earnings_log.push( ['value', 0.45] );

                //Update the old user record
            userSchema.update({_id: '5b93d84aa9d1a300043c4f8f'}, {"eoUsers": newUserRecord_eoUsers});
}
```